# Is there a way to overcome antivirus blocking hosts file with c#?

Tags: c#, antivirus

So I have Avira installed on my device. I need programmatically change 'hosts' file. And trying to do so, Avira shows that the file is blocked and I'm getting an exception that the access to the file is denied. Is there a way to overcome this antivirus restriction with C#?

I don't want to delete or disable antivirus.

Comment: Why are you programmatically changing the hosts file?

Comment: If you can do so, its a huge risk

Comment: Which hosts file specifically, are you talking about the windows hosts file or a specific one for that antivirus package?

Answer (score 2):

- Click the Avira umbrella icon on the right side of the task bar. Your Antivirus product will open.
- Click the cogwheel in the bottom left corner of your Antivirus product. The configuration menu will open.
- Select PC Protection > Real-Time Protection > Exceptions.
- Enter the processes or files and folders you want to be ignored from the scanning process, or browse for your exceptions.
- Click Add to move your selection to the exception window.
- Click Apply and then OK to confirm the changes. The configuration menu will be closed.

I just copy pasted from Avira→[Source](https://blog.avira.com/exceptions-avira-antivirus-3-steps/)

Comment: Would be nice to get solution without changing a thing in avira.

Comment: @Nikas and [I would like a toilet made of solid gold, but it's just not in the cards now, is it?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHnlKzGbqZc). Anyway, there isn't a universal solution because it's 100% dependent on the anti-virus software. If you want to know about alternatives, you could always contact Avira.